# Como validar el capcha de este formulario? mediante ajax?

Tags: php, html, ajax, json, captcha

tengo el siguiente formulario. como lo puedo enviar mediante ajax para ser validado?
tengo esto en html

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
        <input name="email" type="email"  id='email_I' required/>
</td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <div align="center">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LemndMbAAAAADyt_e6Txiek8RQywfbueW-N0zZs" id="recaptcha-token" name="token">

    </div>
    </div>
    </td>
    </tr>

<tr>
<td>
            <input name="button_sign_up" class="redond" id="submite" type="submit" value="Registrar"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<center>            <a href="changue.html">Olvide mi contraseña</a></center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Esto lo tengo en JS Ajax:

```
function envio(){
    var Typo_1 = document.getElementById('submite').value;
    var email_var = document.getElementById('email_I').value;
    var Cap_var = $('#recaptcha-token').val();
    var Parametros = {
        'email'             : email_var,
        'token'             : Cap_var
    };
    $.ajax({
        data: Parametros ,
        url: './Info/recepcion.php',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            $('#per').html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

y esto lo recibe en **recepcion.php** el tema es que no llega nada. ¿Que me falta?

```
$recaptcha= $_POST['token'];
if($recaptcha !=''){$secret="misercretoidwebcapcha*******";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$var = file_get_contents ("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$recaptcha&remoteip=$ip");
}else{die ('<center><font color="red">Por favor colocar capcha 2</font></center>');}
```

¿Algun ejemplo de como enviar la validacion de capcha mediante ajax?

Comment: En la variable Parametros, que le pasas al servidor, no veo que este incluido el valor de la variable Cap_var.

Comment: Obvio es ¿como se hace?

Comment: te hago una pregunta, en tu formulario a la hora de visualizarlo te aparece el captcha??

Comment: si hermano te puedo pasar el link de la web? puedes llenarlo aleatorio no esta activado solo pude un **print_r($_POST);** y el **die(Alerta entro)** despues del insset aun que en el JS hice la insersion todo llega OK pero nunca el capcha

Comment: https://shaiyainternational.createsoftw.com/WebSh/cadastro.html lo he llenado asi **miusuario mipass mipass miemail** NADA se verifica por que estoy solo con el capcha ver si le llega la variable la cual no se envía aun que yo la mande al **.JS**.

Comment: no me carga el captcha bro, solo un input en blanco, porque no lo haces de manera tradicional? usando `action` en el `form` osea: `action="recepcion.php"` y con ajax solo dale para que valide los datos, que realmente estén completos.

Comment: No me sirve pues del lado cliente y no quiero correr el riesgo que desactiven el capcha, necesito si o si que lo valide el ajax que esa variable sea enviada por ajax el peo es que no tengo idea como escribir el html

Comment: creo que puesde ver la estructura exacta del html y el js es func.js esta en http://shaiyainternational.createsoftw.com/WebSh/js/func.js

Comment: quizás te sea útil este artículo https://blog.nubecolectiva.com/como-implementar-recaptcha-v3-de-google-en-un-formulario-html/